# warning: passing argument 1 of 'CGPathMoveToPoint' discards qualifiers from pointer target type

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, warnings

I keep getting this warning 
warning: passing argument 1 of 'CGPathMoveToPoint' discards qualifiers from pointer target type

I am calling the function like this

```
const CGAffineTransform m = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, &m , nextPos.x, nextPos.y);
```

I already tried

```
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL , nextPos.x, nextPos.y);
```

or

```
CGAffineTransform m = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, &m , nextPos.x, nextPos.y);
```

But i always get this error, how do i get rid of it?

Comment: Show the declaration of `path`.

Answer (score 6):

The warning is about argument 1, but all your variations are on argument 2. Try changing argument 1, `path` — probably to get rid of a rogue `const` — and that should fix it.

Comment: Lol, thanks, that was kinda ridiculous. Yeah i started a CGPathRef and it should be CGMutablePathRef. Thanks a bunch, i was crawling the web for a while :P